# Lint rule for preventing shorthand function calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Image you have an array and you want to map the items using a function. You then call:

```
['item1', 'item2'].map((item) => someFunc(item));
```

In typescript this will work fine and if the `someFunc` function does not take a string as param typescript will complain.

The same thing can also be written like:

```
['item1', 'item2'].map(someFunc);
```

This is nicer but if item does not match the `someFunc` param typescript will not complain.

Can I disable the short version using lint or can I make typescript complain about this type of error?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't complain? See this :-
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmAxArmGBeGAKCAXHFAE4CWYA5gJTYB8MokIANkgHQsiX7UDcAKADaAcgCMIgDQwRAJikyAzCIC67BAEMADvnpxEqDL37Cx02dMVrNO+MnRh+QA

Comment: If it can infer the type in the first example it's hard to see how it could not do the same in the second.

Comment: You are right, in the typescript playground it does complain but not in my solution which is weird. I need to go through my settings and see if I messed something up.

Comment: Ah, I have https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes this disabled. That causes the issue I have.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample of the error I have here: [Sample Error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictFunctionTypes=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QPIDsCm0DeAoavoQHsBbVABQCcCAHALnwBdyBLZAcwG4sBfLLUSGPAEAVAO4FMOPIRIVqdCIxYcpuGWUpUATAqVtOqhmHpNg0AGaUiQpGgAULRWGTBUdGxDEEAlNHcJPcUk8EOhyVHoAV3JkaEd6Z1dOEJ4ePgJkRWgwcnIwAE9-ARRUAG0AXWgAXmhSjHxiDXloACIAC1QQEAlxchAAExauct4cvPyAOiIwKjsYKoA%20OACvCctiDxK5729OMYKpmbsPVfXrAJLdoA)

If I disable [strictFunctionTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) I get the error I have. If I turn this on it complains.